# Trying to get property of 'name' non-object

Tags: php, laravel

My model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Products';
    protected $fillable = ['product-code', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'discount', 'image', 'image_alt'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSpecifics');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function find_product(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'code' => 'required|max:50|string'
    ]);
    $Product = Product::where('product-code', '=', $request->get('code'))->first();
    if(strlen($Product->name > 0))
    {
        return view('edit_product', compact('Product'));
    }
    return redirect()->route('edit_product')->with('fail', 'Failed to find the product.');
}
```

Form:

```
            <form action="{{route('find_product')}}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Product Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="code" id="product_code" type="text" placeholder="Enter product code...">
                </div>
                @error('code')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-lg-right">Search for product</button>
                </div>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
```

Whenever I submit the form, I get "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object", what am I doing wrong?
I do have the App/Product included in my controller.

**EDIT:**
Adding "dd($Product);" to my controller provides me with "null" as the answer.

Comment: It seems like there's no product with the code you've specified.

Comment: Check what's in `$Product`

Comment: `print_r($Product)` and update your question with response

Comment: dd($product) gives me null, how should I handle this case correctly? I'm thinking of using the empty() function, but I don't know if that's the best solution, maybe I should just check for "null"?

Comment: To check you found your product check $product ! = null       not if $product->name has a length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question.

```
$product = Product::where('product-code', $request->get('code'))->first(); // remove '='
if($product) // if the product with given code is not found then the $product would be null
{
    return view('edit_product', compact('product'));
}
return redirect()->route('edit_product')->with('fail', 'Failed to find the product.');
```

There are still many coding standard issues in your code. I recommend going through [Laravel Best Pratices](https://www.laravelbestpractices.com/).